# How to detect multiple screen touches with Processing for Android

Tags: android, processing

I am using the Processing platform to prototype an app for Android, but I am having trouble detecting multiple screen touches at the same time.  How does one detect the locations of two screen touches that happen simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is some research. Try googling "Android Processing multitouch" for a ton of results, including these:

- [Can Processing handle multi-touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166522/can-processing-handle-multi-touch)
- [Got Multitouch Working - Processing Forum](https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/got-mult-touch-working.html)

Do the research and **try something**. If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried. Good luck.